# Utilizing WordPress' Admin UI for plugin settings: getting accordion style

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, jquery-ui, admin-ui

As a plugin developer, it's important to make sure the *Dashboard* has the same look-and-feel as the rest of the native components of WordPress to provide a better [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

For my plugin, I want to implement [an accordion](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/accordion.html) in my settings page. [From reading this article](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-style-guide/) and using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#defaults) function, it looks like this is possible by doing the following:

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-accordion' );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $(".accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });
    $(".accordion").last().accordion("option", "icons", false);
});
</script>

<div class="accordion">
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
        <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
```

**Result**

[image: Accordion Example]

This was taken from the [WordPress Admin Pattern Library plugin](https://github.com/helen/wp-style-guide) that I found on GitHub. Yet, in their demo, the accordion example looks like the following:

[image: Expected Result]

The repo looks like it hasn't been maintained and it seems that this is a styling issue. Is there another function that I need to run such as `wp_enqueue_style()` that is natively built in in order to get the proper styling for the accordion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I do it for my plugin/options page (which is inside a class, thus the $this-> construct):

```
/* enqueue our css */
public function enqueue_options_style( $hook ) {
    if( $hook == $this->admin_page )
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-options', '/some-directory/my-options.css', false, $this->version );  // only present for our plugin's settings page
}
```

`$this->admin_page` is the slug returned from prior options page init:

```
$this->admin_page = add_menu_page( __( 'Settings' ), __( 'Settings' ), 'some-user-capability', 'my-options', array( &$this, 'display_page' ), 'dashicons-my-icon' );
```

and, the call to enqueue the options style is hooked thusly:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'enqueue_options_style' ), 10, 1 );     // add the css we need for our options settings page
```

Now, it's just a matter of constructing that `my-options.css` file, with the appropriate markup for your `.accordion h3` element.

Comment: So it looks like by default that the CSS styling isn't native in WordPress' UI.

Comment: grep 'accordion'...WP only ships with the .js they leave the styling up to us.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and showing your setup, this helps.